# What is mvle compiler option in S32 Design Studio

Tags: gcc, compilation, linker, microcontroller

Currently, I am working on Freescale MPC5746B controller. I am using Freescale S32 Design Studio IDE to the compiler and debug the code. S32 Design Studio internally using the GCC compiler.

When I see the generated compiler and linker option in S32 Design Studio, I am not able to get the meaning of some of the compiler options in GCC compiler manual.

I tried to get the information in S32 Design studio manual, but I couldn't find it. Can someone tell me the meanings of these compiler and linker options?

Compiler Option:

1. -DMPC574xC (I assume this option is to select the controller series)
2. -DSTART_FROM_FLASH (Don't know)
3. -DTURN_ON_CPU0 (To select the CPU0, as it is multicore)
4. -mvle (I think it is for variable length encoding - VLE
   instructions give extra flexibility in instruction encoding and alignment, allowing the compiler and linker to greatly reduce the size of runtime object code with only a small penalty in execution performance)

Linker Option:

1. –sections (Don't know)

Comment: The options that start with -D are define statements.  They define preprocessor constants "MPC574xC", "START_FROM_FLASH", and "TURN_ON_CPU0".  You might find these constants used in #ifdef statements in the source code.

Answer (score 1):

`man gcc` on a Unix system shows what `-D` and `-m` options mean. you can find out how the `-D` options affect the compiled code by grepping those strings in the sources. I'm guessing `START_FROM_FLASH` means it will boot from the address reserved for an external SD card.

`-mvle`, as you surmised, enables the `vle` machine option for PowerPC variable-length encoding.

```
NAME
       gcc - GNU project C and C++ compiler

SYNOPSIS
       gcc [-c|-S|-E] [-std=standard]
           [-g] [-pg] [-Olevel]
           [-Wwarn...] [-pedantic]
           [-Idir...] [-Ldir...]
           [-Dmacro[=defn]...] [-Umacro]
           [-foption...] [-mmachine-option...]
           [-o outfile] [@file] infile...
```

`-sections` is not a standard `ld` option. if you can find the executable, and run it from the command line with the `--help` option, it may tell you.

Answer (score 0):

`-DMPC574xC` and others are just defines, similar to `#define MPC574xC`.